# how can we tell if the remote server is multi-threaded?

Tags: c++, multithreading, network-programming, unix

My customer did not gave me details regarding the nature of it's application. It might
be multithreaded it might be not. His server serves SOAP messages (http requests)

Is there any special trick in order to understand if the peer is single or multi threaded?

I don't want to ask the customer and I don't have access to his server/machine. I want to find it myself.

Comment: I do care about the order of the requests and the performance of the feature.

Comment: Also, it may use some kind of connection pool..

Comment: @cateof being multithreaded does not imply high(or low) performance. In many cases the oposite might be true. I suggest you simply ask the customer.

Comment: It might be multithreaded it might be not. It might change in the future.

Comment: Even if it's multi-threaded and sports high-performance, it may not be thread-safe.

Comment: ... or it could be single threaded and still be able to handle multiple requests in parallel. TAO CORBA ORBs is able run in a single thread and at the same time reuse the thread for different requests when it would otherwise be blocked in a synchronous request... which means that when developing for TAO with that configuration you have to write thread safe code even if there is a single thread...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's irrelevant. Why do you feel it matters to you?

A more useful question would be:

> Can the server accept multiple
>   simultaneous sessions?

The answer is likely to be '*yes, of course*' but it's certainly possible to implement a server that's incapable of supporting multiple sessions.

Just because a server supports multiple sessions, it doesn't mean that it's multi-threaded. And, just because it's multi-threaded doesn't mean it will have good performance. When servers need to support many hundreds or thousands of sessions, multi-threading may be a very poor choice for performance.

Are you asking this question because you want to 'overlap' SOAP messages on the same connection - in other words, have three threads send requests, and then all three wait for a response? That won't work, because (like HTTP) request and response messages are paired together on each connection. You would need to open three connections in order to have three overlapped messages.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. The question then is how can we find if the server can accept multiple simultaneous sessions?

Comment: Just try and open two connections at once. If the second one fails, then you'll know. And, you can do this test in one thread.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, at least not without accessing the computer directly.  Multiple connections can even be managed by a single thread, however the good news is that this is highly unlikely.  Most servers use thread pooling and assign a thread to a connection upon a handshake.  Is there a particular reason why you need to know?  If you're presumably going to work on this server, you'll know first-hand how it works.

Comment: If his implementation is single threaded I will also implement a single thread.

Comment: To what end?  You're writing a program to talk to a server?  You'd only need multiple threads if you intended to use multiple connections at once, though more often than not that's not necessary.  Only the server has to worry about multiple connections, not the client.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the server is multithreaded or not. There are good and efficient ways to implement I/O multiplexing without threads [like select(2) and suchlike], if that's what worries you.